# How To Use Local Internet Connection To Access Internet While Still Connected with VPN

Tags: windows-7, internet, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

I need to connect to VPN for work purposes, but I want to be able to use my own internet connection for downloads and general web browsing. I'm using Windows 7, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All connections to "unknown" IP's (anything on your subnet is "known") will go via whatever is setup as your gateway, which after connecting to a VPN is usually via the VPN.

So, you just need to adjust your VPN settings to not provide a gateway so that you return to using your LAN gateway.

However, this *might* break some or all of your VPN services.

Comment: Look at [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/180440/how-to-use-own-internet-connection-for-browsing-while-connected-to-work-vpn/256188#256188) for exact steps

Answer (score 2):

when you make the vpn connection, in it's properties is a setting similar to "use this connection as default gateway" - that'll route all traffic over the vpn link. Uncheck that and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to check what is your gateway, when connect to a VPN.

What type of VPN you connect to ?
Microsoft VPN, Cisco VPN, OpenVPN, What kind of vpn connection ?

Comment: regarding this, Windows 7 sometimes says the VPN connection has internet access. Othertimes it says "No internet access". Obviously "No internet access" on the vpn connection is what I want. Any ideas why Windows 7 confuses the issue? This is after the "Use default gateway on remote machine" is unchecked under tcp/ip (both v4 and 6).

Answer (score 1):

[How To Use Local Internet Connection To Access Internet While Still Connected with VPN](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-use-local-internet-connection-to-access-internet-while-still-connected-with-vpn/) has exact steps to do what [@DMA57361](https://superuser.com/questions/180440/how-to-use-own-internet-connection-for-browsing-while-connected-to-work-vpn/180496#180496) said.

Basically you need to go to `network connections`, open the `VPN connection's properties`, open the `properties of the IPv4` item, click `advanced` and `untick` "Use Default Gateway On Remote Network"

Comment: Link-only answers are not particularly useful and they force people to leave the site to get their answer. Please elaborate your post by explaining the steps required.

Comment: What's wrong in navigating away if visitor of this questions are getting their answer? Anyways I've nothing to do with the linked site. I was just looking to sort out this problem of my own. I first searched it on superuser.com and couldn't find exact steps on this question. Then I looked around on Google and I found it on the other site which solved my problem and I linked that here so that it helps anyone else visiting this question. Now if you want me to paste the steps in the article here, then I think its duplicating things on web and StackExchange is all about making web better I suppose

Comment: I didn't imply you had an affiliation with the linked site, and that's irrelevant to my point. An answer that states "go look over there" isn't useful (and what happens when that link breaks?). This has been discussed at length on [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259), and they are generally discouraged. Also, make sure you check the copyright and license of the original site before you copy/paste.

Comment: I agree with you @DMA57361. Broken link is a problem. See now because of copyright I won't be able to paste whole thing here. Other option is I can type it in my own words and paste my snaps taken from my PC here. Then that will be again duplication of efforts if you see it in wider terms.

Comment: It *is* a duplication of effort, but I'm afraid that's rather the point - SU should be a *source* of knowledge, not a referral service. And the instructions don't have to be all singing and dancing with images, for example, I reckon this would suffice: Go to network connections, open the VPN connection's properties, open the properties of the IPv4 item, click advanced and untick "Use Default Gateway On Remote Network".

Comment: 3 years later and link is fine. Useful answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm still getting negative votes for link only answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but probably not.  You basically need two network connections, one that is tunneled through to your work, and one that is wide open to the world.  One option to achieve this *might* be to use the XP virtual machine, if your version of Win7 supports it.  The VPN software that I was provided with for work would not install on Win7, and so I had to install it on the virtual machine.  As far as I can tell, the tunnel only exists for the (entire) virtual machine, not my host machine connection, however I have not done a route trace to verify this.

Comment: Anything inside the VM should be only inside the VM - so the host system cannot even *see* the VPN. The host system might be relaying the connections to/from the VM, but that should be about it.