# Stop VPN being used on internet traffic on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vpn, routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)
>   [How To Use Local Internet Connection To Access Internet While Still Connected with VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/180440/how-to-use-local-internet-connection-to-access-internet-while-still-connected-wi)

I am using the built in Windows 7 VPN to connect to my work network however when I browse the internet its going through the VPN.  How do I stop this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Use Local Internet Connection To Access Internet While Still Connected with VPN](http://superuser.com/questions/180440/how-to-use-local-internet-connection-to-access-internet-while-still-connected-wi) and/or [Windows 7 VPN how to not tunnel internet?](http://superuser.com/questions/84990/windows-7-vpn-how-to-not-tunnel-internet)

Comment: What type of vpn are you using?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Open Network Connections
- Select VPN connection
- Properties
- TCP/IP - properties
- Advanced
- On General tab uncheck "Use default gateway..."
- OK-OK-OK

Comment: This works on Windows 8 too although the steps to get there differ a bit. But here you uncheck the 'Use default gateway on remote network' option.

Comment: thanks: the main problem for me was that i couldn't send any smtp email

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the default gateway that's being set by your VPN (you might have to ask your work's IT support guy, as it might be a setting that's pushed out from the VPN server). A temporary fix can be obtained as follows:

1. Start a command prompt as administrator.
2. Check your current gateways with `route print` (There will be a lot more, but this is the part you're looking for):

   ```
   IPv4 Route Table
   ===========================================================================
   Active Routes:
   Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
             0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       XX.YY.48.1     XX.YY.50.199     20
             0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.107   4000
      10.254.254.252  255.255.255.252         On-link    10.254.254.253    286
   ```

   (Your Metrics might be different, and your IPs will likely be different, but you can see I have two default gateways here (the `0.0.0.0` entries) One of them will correspond to your internet, and one will correspond to your VPN.)
3. Delete the appropriate gateway with `route delete 0.0.0.0 <gateway>`. In this example, to delete the `192.168.0.1` gateway, we'd use `route delete 192.168.0.1`
   Don't worry too much about making a mistake here; the routing table is regenerated every time you reboot the machine, or connect/disconnect from a network. If you get the wrong gateway and take down all of your internet, just reboot and reconnect.

This is only a temporary fix. Ideally, you'd contact your tech support at your work and ask him how to make the VPN stop pushing a default gateway. Another alternative is to adjust the metric of the VPN gateway, so that the system prefers the non-VPN connection (as you can see in the example, while I have two gateways, one is set with a really high metric (think "cost") to use it, and so the system only uses it if it has no other choice).

Comment: Is there a reason you downvoted this post?

Comment: My comment was removed, but I'll try to repeat: "RTFM!" and compare with **my** answer

Comment: Comparing answers, we have two different answers that accomplish the same means. Neither is wrong.