# In Mac OS X, is there a way to individually route apps through a VPN or not?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, vpn, routing

I've seen plenty of information on selectively routing (through a VPN or other interface) by subnet or IP. But is there a way, in OS X, to selectively route through a VPN by application? Could one, for example, have one browser use the VPN and another not? I would think it could be as simple as telling individual apps what network interface to use, but I don't see an obvious way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate, (and answer to your question) [here](http://superuser.com/questions/216554/how-to-route-certain-applications-through-a-vpn-and-others-to-use-my-standard)

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/251051/is-it-possible-to-route-only-a-specific-application-through-a-vpn) may also help.