# How do I route my traffic through my internet connection instead of VPN?

Tags: windows-7, internet, vpn, routing

At the company I work we used to have a PPTP VPN connection and all I would have to do to use my internet connection and not pass through the company network to download files from the internet was to uncheck this option on the network adapter called "Use remote gateway". Doing this I could download files using my 20MB internet connection instead of passing through the VPN and downloading at 2MB and still have access to VPN ressources.

They have now "upgraded" the VPN connection to ipsec, we use the Watchguard VPN client and I don't seem to find the option to route internet traffic through my connection instead of the VPN.

Can anyone help?
Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps look into something like this: http://superuser.com/q/12022/160458

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they don't allow split tunnelling

As this is all handled on the other end, you may want to contact them and see what they suggest. For the time being you may just disconnect from vpn while downloading large file. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I´m taking a wild guess your company uses XTM devices .It sounds like your IT guys have checked the "Allow all traffic through tunnel" option in the "ressources" tab of your Mobile VPN Settings. You might just ask somebody to uncheck it for you, although they probably won´t, because this option is more secure.