# Can I specify network usage when connected to multiple networks?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, network-traffic

Given: I have a wireless (or wired) connection to the internet.
Given: I am connected to a dial-up/VPN connection over the internet using Windows VPN.

By default under this setup, ALL traffic winds up going over the VPN connection. 
However I really only need the VPN in order to remote in to a development server.

Is it possible to somehow tell the system that I want the remote connection to go over the VPN, but that browser traffic, email, etc. should all just go out over the underlying and basic internet connection, and NOT go through the VPN?

I am running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

I am open to directing traffic via port rules, or based on exe name, or whatever.

Comment: This could be a violation of the terms in whatever agreement you signed to gain VPN access.  Generally, a company would not want a computer which has established a VPN connection to simultaneously have an additional, unfiltered connection to the Internet.

Comment: @Iszi: Which doesn't make much sense to me, given that computers *do not* bridge the two connections by default. (Admittedly, I've only used privately-managed VPNs, so don't know much about how stuff works.)

Comment: Every VPN I've ever used for a company required that all traffic go through their VPN proxy.  To do anything else opens up their network to intrusion through your connection.  I much prefer how my current company works, offering instead a remote desktop setup that allows me to remote in to my workstation and work through that.

Comment: @grawity - But if their machine has been compromised, they can easily bridge that connection without the user knowing and thus gain access to the network connected by the VPN.

Comment: @BBlake: If the machine has been compromised, it might just as well have malware that can wait, offline, for the connection to be established.

Comment: True.  But that was always the reasoning given by IT support at my previous jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... When i asked my question, i perused the "related" questions that came up when i tabbed out of the title box, and none matched or had answers that helped.

However, AFTER posting my question, one of the related questions in the sidebar DID have the answer.

Find that answer here: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network/12093#12093) .

Basically, *right-click the VPN connection > Properties > Networking > dbl-click IPv4 and IPv6 > Advanced > IP Settings* and turn off `Use default gateway on remote network`.

I did NOT need to do any of the messing around with adding routes or any of that though.

I can connect to the machine to which I needed to VPN, and other traffic is still routing over the regular internet connection. I verified things are going where expected with numerous `tracert`s to numerous hosts.