# Running a VPN connection inside a Hyper-V VM on Windows 8, irregular issues

Tags: windows, vpn, hyper-v

So im running Windows 8 Enterprise x64 on a computer here with the Hyper-V role installed and i want to use this to VPN to work in order to access some server etc, and avoid dropping my connection on the home computer when VPN is being setup.

The W8 is connected to my home network which has an Asus RT-N66U which acts as router/dhcp/dns.

Everything works fine in the VM before i set up VPN connection. I can access the internet, ping other machines on my home network etc.

I then dial my VPN connection inside the VM using the needed Sonicwall application and this will connect successfully, giving the VM IP etc.

Then the problem arises. I cannot ping any IPs on my work network, cannot access any internal websites. Cannot use RDP etc. It does seem that nothing really works as expected except for the fact that the VPN is connected and i have gotten an IP.

And the kicker is that every other time i connect everything will work as expected. I can ping IPs and connect to servers etc. I just dont get why it doesnt work ALL the time.

Anyone got any tips regarding this? If any more information is required i will try to provide, just let me know.

Comment: "and avoid dropping my connection on the home computer when VPN is being setup" -- why not just use split tunnelling to accomplish this instead?  Are you sure the Sonicwall VPN client is W8 compatible?

Comment: The VM is running ON a windows 8 OS, the actual OS inside the VM (which is running sonicwall) is Windows 7. And as far as i know there are no issues with it. 

Im not familiar with split tunnelling so ill have to look into that. 
Thanks in advance tho!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

Comment: It’s possible the intermittent problem is an issue with Sonicwall itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

1. Disconnect VPN
2. Open command prompt as admin
3. Run

   ```
   route add 192.x.x.0 mask 255.x.x.x 192.x.x.x /p
   ```

   reconnect the VPN and try again.