# A separate network card for p2p traffic

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ethernet, p2p

I have a motherboard with 2 ethernet outlets. Is there a way to route all p2p traffic though one (with VPN) and the rest through the other without VPN? I am on Windows 7.

EDIT: there are [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network) for routing traffic for a specific IP address through the VPN connection, but I'd like to route the type of traffic (p2p) through the VPN connection. Also, creating a virtual machine is a possibility but I'd like to see if there is another way first.

EDIT2: Also, solution above uses a single network card, I am wondering if having a second network card can play a role in the setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes its possible.  You would have to setup split tunneling.

Comment: Usually p2p clients have the option to bind to a specific local IP address.