# How do you disable the use of internet on an adapter?

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm connected to the internet through wifi. I'm also a VPN client and on the other end there is another internet connection. Ever since I joined the VPN I'm getting derpy download speeds and high latency, I'm suspecting due to windows trying to aggregate the connection through the VPN virtual adapter. I only want the VPN for accessing the servers in the VPN, how do I tell windows to not use the internet provided by that virtual adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/q/12022/450150) I think you should be able to adapt that to your use case.

Comment: I've red a bunch of stuff regarding my question, all of them (including the link you posted) want me to uncheck the "use default gateway on remote network" but I have no such checkbox there, instead I have an empty listbox titled "default gateways".

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the _General_ tab of your _Advanced TCP/IP Settings_ for the VPN connection? I can't exactly imagine how that would look right now.

Comment: It is win 7 connected through softether, anyways, I fixed it by removing the gateway from the server (it creates a default one when enabling DHCP for the tunnel adapters).