# Set up VPN to only work for Remote Desktop?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, windows-10

I have a company VPN I need to connect to before I can remote into my workstation

How can I configure my home network to only route the remote desktop data via the VPN and let everything else on the machine go via the regular?

Comment: Hi - you'll need to contact the it dept in your company to find out whether 'split tunneling' is enabled on the vpn server.

Comment: @JimNielsen though this looks quite local? (so maybe, what you speak of - split tunneling) isn't necessary? http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network   Though that link  doesn't include specifying port. Not sure off hand if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a route to your home network fixes this.

Also, unchecking "Use default gateway [...]" on General tab of TCP/IP Advanced 
from your VPN connection Properties should fix it.

The gateway way is recommended, and routing only in case that does not work.

Comment: I'd appreciate some elaboration on the steps to do this, as well as how to ensure that it actually works.

Comment: If you unchecked the default gateway option, you can test relatively easy the default path by checking the external IP address used for browsers (check if reported IP is the local machine's connection one or the remote's one). As for the route, adding it is only one command line, but it depends on your current exact IP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On Wins10, open Control Panel.
Go to >Network and Internet>Network and Sharing Center, then click "Connections" of the newly created active networks. choose Properties, then TCP/IPv4 and choose Properties, check Use the following DNS Server addresses. 
fill in with Google DNS.8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4
i could solve it with method above maybe worth yourself a try.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this on Windows 10 by enabling SplitTunneling.
Firstly (thanks to Kent Chen):
https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-local-internet-connection-to-access-internet-while-still-connected-with-vpn
There is still the known issue.

You can configure split tunnelling using PowerShell:
From PowerShell, type:

```
Get-VpnConnection
```

If SplitTunneling is set to False, take note of the VPN name and enter the following command:

```
Set-VpnConnection "Demo VPN" -SplitTunneling1
```

Note: Replace "Demo VPN" with your VPN name
Verify SplitTunneling is now set to True
This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions ([not just links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to adequately address both of these elements.