# Client to client route on Windows VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, windows-server-2012, pptp

I'm trying to configure a PPTP VPN network to play LAN games. The structure is shown in the picture below:

[image: Network structure]

As you can see, Client 1, Client 2 and Client 3 establish a VPN connection (using the standard VPN interface integrated in Windows) to the VPN server (Windows Server 2012, which uses the default "Incoming connection" interface to accept incoming VPN requests), so there's no third party software.

The connection is successfully established (the port 1723 is already forwarded on each router), but when a client tries to host a game, the other clients cannot see it (the exception for the ports used by the game is already set on the firewall of each client), so I assume that there is no direct communication between each client.

I've tried to uncheck the "Use default gateway on remote network" on each client, but this did not solve the issue.

What I'm trying to do now is add some static routes, but I did not fully understand how they work...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the static routes simply run the following commands on your clients after being connected through the VPN with `<VPN>` being replaced by the name of your VPN connection:

```
netsh interface ip show config name=<VPN>
```

Remember what's listed under "IP Address". (Also, there is the "Subnet Prefix" entry which should tell you your network address according to your plans.)

Now you just need to get this odd interface number by running the following and looking at the number before the dots next to your VPN connection in the "Interface List":

```
route print -4
```

With these information by hand you can now run the following in an elevated prompt:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 <IP> IF <IF>
```

Where `<IP>` is the IP address and `<IF>` the interface number acquired before.

Running this command should do it. Confirm using `ping`/`tracert`, also maybe have again a look at `route print -4`, it should tell you what route a packets addressed to a certain location will take.

BTW, looking at your plan you might want to rethink having local networks with the same network addresses and especially the same client IPs?! This can't work out, on one and the same the network the IPs should be unique and you should normally only have one network connection per network, in this case you have a local one **and** and one through the VPN.

/edit: See also the script I posted at [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network/992051#992051) (or another script posted in that thread).

Comment: I tried the route you suggested but it didn't work or better: the game uses SSDP protocol to discover lobbies on the network, or direct connection by writing the IP address of the PC that hosts the game... if i try to discover the lobbies, it cannot find anything... instead if i make a direct connection by IP the connection is established but when the game starts, it says "Waiting for other user to connect"... however what do you mean by having only one network connection? the PCs are connected to the Internet because of the router, so they must be connected to the LAN (and the VPN of course)

Answer (score -1):

Question: What do you want to do?

1. peer to peer

   Windows only allow one VPN user to connect to another user, so this will not work.
2. use a server to share and distribute the game on a user or client PC

   Windows Server does not like to share a user or client to another user or client, so this will not work either.

With Windows, the server needs to have the game on that you want to share,
also if you want to share a client you need software on the server to 'route' the other 'clients' to the 'serving client'. (The server is just a glorified router!)

if you want to share the game on a PC you need software on that PC, to have multiple clients connect to it, as that Windows only allows one VPN or remote at a time.