# How to make selected applications use VPN while others use direct connection?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm on Windows 10 Pro and want certain games/applications to use VPN because of high latency issues. Most of the VPN services have limited bandwidth so I want to allow only specific applications to use the said VPN.
I've read somewhere that it can be done with Policy but there are no instructions on how to do it.

**Update 1**
I'm not using any VPN client, only the built-in one in Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Completely depends on the VPN client and is usually based around routing tables. There isn’t enough information here to help.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm not using any VPN client, only the built-in in Windows 10

Comment: Then you need to [enable split tunneling](http://www.electricmayhemsolutions.net/blog/windows-10-and-a-new-vpn-connection-unable-to-open-networking-properties-on-ipv4-solved/) and [create static routes](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network) for services you want to go through the tunnel based on IP address.