# How to access an IIS hosted website while the IIS Server is connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, iis

I have exposed my home router's public IP address to a GoDaddy domain. Internally, I am port forwarding ports 80 and 443 to a computer on the internal network so that I can access a website I am hosting on IIS 10. I am able to access the website correctly when the Windows 10 computer is not connected to a VPN. However, once I connect to my company's VPN, I am no longer able to connect to the website externally from my network. It is still accessible internally.

When I look at the internal network IP, it does not change after connecting to the VPN. What kind of diagnostic steps can I take to make this website available externally while my computer is connected to my company's VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this approach of unticking the "use default gateway on remote network"

[How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)